# Java Riddle with finally block and recursion

Tags: java, syntax

I just prepared a game for our team about java riddles. So to say, small pieces of java code that do things that you do not expect at the first glance.

While googeling for such riddles I also scribbled around in my IDE and tried out some weird things that you would never write in production code. Just for the fun of it.

Suddenly I came up with the following:

```
public static int cnt = 0;
public static int blubb() {
    try {
        cnt++;
        return blubb();
    } finally {
        return cnt;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(cnt + ": " + Main.blubb() + ": " + cnt);
}
```

When executed it prints something like "0: 21245: 21245" where 21245 is different for each run.

I'd expect either an endless recursion, or returning 1 in the finally block `(0: 1: 1)`

When adding a catch block to catch Throwable and debugging, the debugger will never stop in this block.

Can somebody explain me what is going on here?

Comment: add a catch to see if you have a StackOverflowError

Comment: Hint: when you dont understand what your code is doing: then A) learn how to use a debugger and/or B) simply add print statements. Albeit, as jhamon implies, the "problem" here is that you are leaving out the "catch" of the try/catch/finally construct.

Comment: This explains the problem: http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/Finally "If you return or throw from a finally, then values returned or thrown from the try-catch block will be ignored." A `StackOverflowError` will be thrown, but it is being ignored.

Comment: I tried this. There is no exception. The debugger suddenly stops in the finally block after hitting the recursive call several hundred times

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `catch` block like this, and not seeing a stack trace, doesn't indicate that nothing was thrown:

```
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
      throw t;
    } finally { ... }
```

Not being able to print the stack trace of a `StackOverflowError` immediately after catching a `StackOverflowError` is expected: a SOE literally means that no more method calls can be made.

But to invoke `printStackTrace()`, you need to make another method call. So, *that* method call actually results in another, separate `StackOverflowError`, which you don't attempt to print. But then the `return` in the finally causes the `StackOverflowError` to be discarded.

Try this, which doesn't require a method invocation when the `StackOverflowError` is thrown:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static int cnt = 0;

  private static Throwable caught;

  public static int blubb() throws Throwable {
    try {
      cnt++;
      return blubb();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      caught = t;
      throw t;
    } finally {
      return cnt;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(cnt + ": " + Main.blubb() + ": " + cnt);
    System.out.println(caught);
  }
}
```

For me, this prints:

```
0: 9672: 9672
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

So yes, a `StackOverflowError` was caught.

Answer (score 1):

You create an infinite recursion loop.

At one time the call stack get so big it throws an `StackOverflowError` and you your app should crash.

BUT you set the recursive call in a `try` block. So the exception is partially handled, while not being displayed as you don't have a `catch` block.

As you have a `finally` block returning the value of `cnt`, the many calls in the stack return the value, then returning `19543` or whatever number of times it was called before the exception.

TL;DR : when using a `try` block, don't hide the exception

Comment: Nope. That cannot be the full answer. Even when catching Throwable and printing the stack trace... and even when debugging: The stacktrace is never printed to the console, the debugger never stops in the catch block. It just suddenly stops in the finally block after having stopped severel hundred times on the recursive call.

Comment: @user2542461 if the stack has overflowed, it's not possible to make the method calls required to print the stack trace: another `StackOverflowError` is thrown.